# Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView Error when loading .STL model in Angular 9

Tags: angular, three.js, stl

I want to add a 3d model view on my website using the stl-model-viewer described below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-stl-model-viewer
But I can't make it working. I went through the installation steps, but it still doesn't work. I have the .stl model in the same directory as the  component in which I want to make the model visible

```
<div class="fillscreen">
    <p>store-product-details works!</p>

</div>

<stl-model-viewer [stlModelFiles] = '["./standing.stl"]'></stl-model-viewer>
```

The error I am getting is below:

[image]

Any suggestions on what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Can you import the STL file (via drag'n'drop) in the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/)?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work correcty. I dragged and dropped the file and it displayed the model. I could rotate it, zoom in etc

Comment: I think you report this issue at the GitHub repository of `angular-stl-model-viewer`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved.
'["./standing.stl"]' was incorrect. The proper way to do it is to place the .stl file in assets folder and use '["assets/standing.stl"]'